# Why typescript value becomes of type "any"

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, pinia

So it seems that for some reason, not sure who's fault it is - typescript type is not being recognized...

As an example, I'm using "pinia@next" npm package, and here's a simple demo code:

*(This is the only file in the folder together with single package installed `npm install pinia@next`)*

```js
import { defineStore, Store } from "pinia";

export type State = {
  anyProperty: string
};

export const useAccountStore = defineStore("account", {
  state: () => ({} as State),
});

var test = useAccountStore() as Store<"account", State>;
```

And in this piece of code:

1. "useAccountStore" has a correct type
   [image]
2. "StoreDefinition" type is a function that returns "Store" as a return type:
   [image]
3. VS Code thinks it returns an "any" type:

[image]

4. Even, when I explicitly cast it to "Store" type, it results in "any"
   [image]

- VS Code version: 1.64.1
- VS Code typescript version: 4.5.5

Any ideas what might be happening?

- It doesn't seem to be an issue with package itself, as I haven't found any similar issues on the internet as well as on tutorials on YouTube I can see that people are getting strong type without any additional steps... Thus this must be an issue with my Typescript configuration/version or something?
- I did upgrade my Visual Studio Code to latest version
- In Visual Studio Code dev tools - I cannot see no warnings nor errors related with typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Store` is defined in [pinia's types.js file](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/blob/v2/packages/pinia/src/types.ts) as

```
export type Store<
  Id extends string = string,
  S extends StateTree = {},
  G /* extends GettersTree<S>*/ = {},
  // has the actions without the context (this) for typings
  A /* extends ActionsTree */ = {}
> = _StoreWithState<Id, S, G, A> &
  UnwrapRef<S> &
  _StoreWithGetters<G> &
  // StoreWithActions<A> &
  (_ActionsTree extends A ? {} : A) &
  PiniaCustomProperties<Id, S, G, A> &
  PiniaCustomStateProperties<S>
```

If any of these resolve to `any` then the whole thing does.

Comment: Got me on track, thanks!
It seems that "UnwrapRef" is unknown type in my case